# no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1" - Build by Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

When I try to build a new image to Kubernetes, I got this error:

> `**unable to decode "K8sDeploy.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"**`

Thie error began when I updated the Kubernetes version, here my version info:

```
Client Version: v1.19.2
Server Version: v1.16.13
```

[image]

I tried also to build by my localhost and does work, but by Jenkins don't.

Somebody knows to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just check for case sensitivity in YAML file

In my case it was 'kind' field

`kind: deployment`

changed it to...

`kind: Deployment`

Answer (score 1):

To check what `apiVersion` supports a `Deployment` resource in your **kubernetes** cluster you may run:

```
$ kubectl explain deployment | head -2
```

and you can be almost sure that the result will be as follows:

```
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  apps/v1
```

All modern **kubernetes** versions use `apps/v1`, which was available since `v1.9`, so for quite a long time already. As you may see [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/), older versions which were still available in **kubernetes** `1.15` have been deprecated in `1.16`.

> Client Version: v1.19.2 Server Version: v1.16.13

As stated above, in **kubernetes** `1.16`, `Deployment` **must use** `apps/v1` and there is no possibility to use older api versions like `extensions/v1beta1`, `apps/v1beta1` or `apps/v1beta2` which were still avilable in `1.15`.

Your issue seems to me rather an error from **Jenkins** (possibly old version of **Jenkins** itself or **some of its plugins** or perhaps something with its configuration) which is not able to recognize/parse the correct (and currently required) `apiVersion` for `Deployment` resource.

For troubleshooting purpose you can try and change the `apiVersion` to one of the listed above. This should give you a different error (this time from kubernetes API server) as in `1.16` it won't be able to recognize it.

But at least it should give you a clue. If with older `apiVersion` your **Jenkins** doesn't complain any more, it would mean that it is set to work with older API versions and an update may help.

I see you filed an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/24888) on **kubernetes GitHub** so let's wait what they say, but as I said before to me it doesn't look like an issue with **kubernetes** but rather with **Jenkins** ability to parse a legitimate `Deployment` `yaml`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem started after updating the Kubernetes version, right now I updated the Kubernetes plugins in Jenkins and Jenkins himself, however, the same error still persists.

Comment: Yes, I understand it happend after **kubernetes** update but basically it doesn't mean it has to be related with **kuberntes**.  As I said, the above error message `"**unable to decode "K8sDeploy.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"** "` comes from **Jenkins**, not **kubernetes**. Anyway, such message from kubernetes wouldn't make much sense as in every modern version (starting from `1.9`) `Deployments` are handled by `apps/v1`. From which version have you updated your cluster ?

Comment: Could you also post the entire content of the above mentioned `K8sDeploy.yaml` ?

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Kubernetes version from 1.5 to 1.9, when i force the Kubectl command, does work, just by Jenkis doesn't, as you request follow my k8sdeploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cbbox
  labels: 
    app: cbbox  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
     matchLabels:
       app: cbbox 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cbbox
    spec:
      containers:      
      - image: myregistryrepository
        name: cbbox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: SECRET_DB_IP
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_DB_IP
          - name: SECRET_DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_DB_PASSWORD
          - name: SECRET_DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_DB_USER
          - name: SECRET_LDAP_DOMAIN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_LDAP_DOMAIN
          - name: SECRET_LDAP_URLS
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_LDAP_URLS
          - name: SECRET_LDAP_BASE_DN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_LDAP_BASE_DN
          - name: SECRET_TIME_ZONE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cbboxsecret
                key: SECRET_TIME_ZONE
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acrcredentials
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cbbox
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: cbbox
```